# Python interpreter version in MicroPython not plausible

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I try to determine the interpreter version of a MicroPython port running on a Raspberry Pi Pico W (RP2 port) to know which language features are (not) supported. Provided Python version does not support some features I am using. In REPL I execute:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.4.0; MicroPython v1.20.0-484-g5473200aa on 2023-09-15
>>> print(sys.version_info)
(3, 4, 0)
```

As I understand, this guarantees compatibility to Python 3.4.0. I use `bytes.hex()` with `sep` parameter, available in Python 3.8 and later according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```
>>> b'\xd8:\xdd6-\xb9'.hex(':')
d8:3a:dd:36:2d:b9
```

How to obtain underlying Python interpreter version?

Comment: MicroPython is not Python. It implements syntax equivalent to Python 3.4.0 with some extensions. There are some incompatible differences between MicroPython and Python. It doesn't make sense to ask for "the underlying Python version".

Comment: Thank you, @larsks! Then I guess I can finally just try out the things, that are not clearly documented in the MicroPython docs.